# show all array with vue.js and bootstrap

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, vue.js

Hi with my script i can show only the first reccord because [0]
what should i do to show all reccords ? because sometimes are only one reccord and sometimes many.

```
<v-tab :title="sitePartGSM[0].serial_no" v-if="sitePartGSM[0]">
    <div v-for="siteParts in sitePartGSM">
        {{ siteParts.serial_no }}
        <div class="description" v-for="item in siteParts.part_attributes">
            <small>
                <strong>{{item.x_name}}</strong>
                {{item.x_value}}
            </small>
        </div>
    </div>
</v-tab>
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi can use a index inside v-for for example

```
<div v-for="(siteParts, index) in sitePartGSM">
    <v-tab :title="sitePartGSM[index].serial_no" v-if="sitePartGSM[index]">
        {{ siteParts.serial_no }}
        <div class="description" v-for="item in siteParts.part_attributes">
            <small>
                <strong>{{item.x_name}}</strong>
                {{item.x_value}}
            </small>
        </div>
    </v-tab>
</div>
```

with this method you can see all records

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over all your `sitePartGSM` elements and show them in your `v-tab`.

When using `v-for` you should define a `:key` attribute to improve the rerendering procedure has mentioned in the [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key)

```
<v-tab v-for="siteParts in sitePartGSM" :title="siteParts.serial_no" :key="siteParts.serial_no">
  <div>
    {{ siteParts.serial_no }}
    <div class="description" v-for="item in siteParts.part_attributes" :key="item.x_name">
      <small><strong>{{item.x_name}}</strong> {{item.x_value}}</small>
    </div>
  </div>
</v-tab>
```